# How do I get the attributes of a tag?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, html-select

Been looking everywhere, I just can't seen to find it (probably because I'm wording it wrong or something).

In have a simple select tag in a from with several options. Each option has an `id` attribute. I want to get the `id` from the selected options.

The name of the select tag is "group", so in the servlet I call:

```
String group = request.getParameter("group");
```

This only returns the "label" of the option (the name of it, what the user sees). I don't want that, I want the id of it. I tried

```
String group = request.getParameterValues("group");
```

but that just returns an array with one item, the label of the option.

How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `value` attribute of the `option` tag to what you want to get from servlet:

```
   <select name="parent">
     <c:forEach items="${parents}" var="parent">
       //      here set value="yourid"
       <option value="${parent.id}">${parent.name}
     </c:forEach>
   </select>
```

Comment: Thanks! Just curious though, so there is no way to actually get the id? Is the value the only thing?

Comment: That's how HTML works. This is unrelated to JSP. JSP is just a HTML code generator.